# syntax for using "Not if" statement

Tags: jquery

Is this syntactically correct.

```
success: function(results) {         
            if (results.d.Name.length > 1) {       
               if (!(results.d.Id > 0)){      
                  results.d.Id = 0;    
               }
               var html = '<img style="float:left; height:100px;" src="inc/images/'
               + results.d.Id + '.gif" />' 
               // more code;
            }
         }
```

OK the reason I am wanting a zero is because if the id=1235344 is not assigned I need to show the 0.gif (default image). How can I achieve this.

Comment: Aziz can you but back the } to close the function ...

Comment: "not if"? sounds like a MS proprietary statement

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking in your new edit.

Comment: you want to change the src of an img tag if the id is inferior to zero ? please give more details ...

Comment: okay. Basically the whole purpose of having a zero was that I am dispalying the following html.
vat html=<img style="float:left; height:100px;" src="inc/images/' + results.d.EpmId + '.gif" />'. So the gif images are numbered as 123213.gif, or 34335345.gif. Now if the id's don't exists I show the default image which I have names 0.gif

Comment: So then add your line in the "more code" part of my code (at the end of my answer) and you should be good to go.

Comment: This is what I did as per your instructions:
   success: function(results) {
            if (results.d.Name.length > 1) {
              
                    results.d.Id = results.d.Id || 0;
               
                var html = '<img style="float:left; height:100px;" src="inc/images/' + results.d.Id + '.gif" />'

Comment: @Sangeeta, can you explain how do you know if image exists or not? what is the value of `result.d.id` when the image doesn't exist?

Comment: Thank you Aziz, sorry it was late yesterday and I called it a night. Anyway the data is coming from a webservice and it returns an int id which contains 5 digits. If for some reason it does not find it it returns a null.

Comment: @Sangeeta, ok, based on what you explained, the current code in your question should work correctly. If it is not working, can you explain what is the problem that happens?

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't the opposite of a greater than (`>`) be less than (`<`)?

So instead of:

```
if (!results.d.Id > 0)
```

Try:

```
if (results.d.Id < 0)
```

---

**Per your comment:** Then just do this:

```
if (!results.d.Id)
    results.d.Id = 0;
```

The `!` operator returns false if the variable is either `false`, `null`, undefined, 0, or an empty string. An even simpler way to do it would be this:

```
results.d.Id = results.d.Id || 0;
```

If the ID has already been set (and is non-zero), then keep it, else set it to zero. This way you don't even need an `if` statement. So your end result would look something like this:

```
success: function(results) {         
    if (results.d.Name.length > 1) {       
        results.d.Id = results.d.Id || 0;
        // more code;
    }
}
```

Comment: depend what he want to achieve ... but we don't really know

Comment: Well the way he/she has it right now doesn't make sense. You're comparing to see if a boolean is greater than zero. Which I guess could be a test for true, but I really doubt that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: I am not sure this is part of a ajax json and returns the results.d

I have defined Id as int but its not working. I want to assign a 0 if it is a blank or nullor a 0;

Comment: Also, he's setting back to 0, so it's just < 0, not <= 0, otherwise you could be resetting 0, to 0

Comment: The complement ("opposite") of the > operator is not the < operator, it's the <= operator. However it doesn't make much difference in this case, as overwriting zero with zero or not doesn't change the result.

Comment: @Guffa: I realize this, but I changed it per @Kyle's comment.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://docs.rinet.ru/StilnyeKofe/ch13.htm#Orderofprecedence), the `!` (not) operator is executed before the `>` (comparison).

replace this

```
            if (!results.d.Id > 0) {
```

with this

```
            if (!(results.d.Id > 0)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The closing braces are missing, and I added `(` and `)` in your condition

```
success: function(results) {
    if (results.d.Name.length > 1) {
        if (!(results.d.Id > 0)) {
            results.d.Id = 0;
        }
        //more code;
    }
}
```